# Websocket-client Python disable output

Tags: python-2.7, logging, websocket

I am using the `websocket-client` Python Package. This works fine. But when I send messages to the server the client prints this message to stdout. Is there a possibility to disable this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`websocket.enableTrace(False)` solved this.

Comment: Since you answered your own question, please remember to [accept your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) after the 48 hour waiting period has passed.